# How to read text of textedit object from QTabWIdget C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtabwidget, qfile

I have called same **TextEdit** object whenever new tab is created. But the text on other tabs are inaccessible. How can I get the text from other **TextEdit** that are opened in new tabs.

I am trying to save text in a file.

same **TextEdit** in every new tab

[image: 1]

```
void MainWindow::on_actionsavew_triggered()
{
    QString file_name = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Open the file","X://");
        QFile file(file_name);
        if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","File not Open");
            return;
        }
        QTextStream out(&file);
        QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
       out<<text;
       file.flush();
       file.close();
}
```

Comment: how do you add new tabs?

Comment: void MainWindow::on_actionNew_Tab_triggered()
{
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QTextEdit(ui->textEdit), QString("Tab %0").arg(ui->tabWidget->count()+1));
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);
}

Answer (score 0):

this here

```
QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
```

is a a hint to us indicating that you are actually adding those widgets to the tabs and windows using the qt designer in qt creator, therefore you can access ANY widget and its attributes using the same approach

e.g.

do

```
QString textFromTab1 = ui->textEditInTab1->toPlainText();
```

Comment: There's same TextEdit in every tab.

Comment: how can that be? are you moving back and forward the Widget????

Comment: There's same text edit in every new tab also. The code is only working for first tab.

Comment: void MainWindow::on_actionNew_Tab_triggered()
{
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new **QTextEdit(ui->textEdit)**, QString("Tab %0").arg(ui->tabWidget->count()+1));
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);
}